# How to insert a record with a date in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO P_RESV_UNIT
(RESV_UNIT_ID, RATE_CODE,RESV_NUM,SEGMENT_CODE,PM_UNIT_TYPE_ID,HSKEEPING_SERVICE_CODE,ARRIVAL_DATE,DEPARTURE_DATE)
VALUES ('5000000000','OTC','507082784','DV','10676','WKL',TO_DATE('9/9/2013','dd/mon/yyyy'),TO_DATE('9/9/2013','dd/mon/yyyy'));
```

But I keep getting an error : not a valid month.

How do you enter it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make it as follows

```
 TO_DATE('09/SEP/2013','DD/MON/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `to_date` functions to be `to_date('9/9/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` using `mm` instead of `mon`.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to use date literals instead:

```
DATE '2013-09-09'
```